# Was there ever a time that the crew of the Enterprise-E would have worn TNG S1-7 / DS9 / Generations-style uniforms?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise, jean-luc-picard, starfleet-rank, star-trek-uniforms

In 'First Contact', La Forge makes reference to the crew of the Enterprise-E having been in space for over a year by that point. Given that the revised ST:FC Starfleet uniforms (grey shoulders) were introduced in 'First Contact', and we have an opportunity to observe Starfleet uniform protocol in the year preceding 'First Contact' (by watching 'DS9' and noting when the uniforms change), is it reasonable to assume that Picard and co. spent some time on board the E, rocking the uniforms from the TNG TV era?

*** EDIT ****

I was correctly reminded that in 'Generations' we saw a gradual shift from the 'TNG' TV-era uniforms to the 'DS9'-style uniforms.

However, my question is now: "is it reasonable to assume that Picard and co. spent some time on board the E, rocking the uniforms from the 'Generations'/'DS9' era?"

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

In *Star Trek Generations*, we see the uniform has changed from the *TNG* TV Era (image 1) to a uniform more resembling the uniforms worn at first on *DS9* (image 2)

Starfleet uniforms from the *TNG* TV Era changed four times:

1. [Starfleet uniform Type A (2353-2367/2370)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_%282350s-2370s%29) (TNG TV Era)

[image]

2. [Starfleet uniform Type B (2366 - end of the decade)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_%282350s-2370s%29) (TNG TV Era)

[image]

3. [Starfleet uniform (late 2360s-2372)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_%28late_2360s-early_2370s%29) (*Generations*)

[image]

4. [Starfleet uniform](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_%282370s%29) (2370s) (*First Contact* onwards)

[image]

Now, the *Enterprise-E* was launched in 2372, stardate 49827.5 with Picard assuming control shortly thereafter ([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Enterprise_E)).  According to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_%282370s%29), the Starfleet Uniform was modified to the last of the three (i.e. the 'grey' uniforms) in ***2373***.  As the *Enterprise-E* was launched a *year prior* to that re-design, **yes, the crew of the *Enterprise-E* would have spent some time 'rocking' in the *Generations*-style uniform for about a year.**

Comment: +1!  Minor point: in the background of the *Generations* shot, several crew are still wearing the old uniforms, namely Worf and Troi.

Comment: @Praxis good pick-up: your wish is my command!

Comment: Hehe.  Your answer has gone from excellent to *perfect*.

Comment: I always thought it was nice that they had both the *TNG* TV uniforms and the *DS9* uniforms in *Generations*.  Riker notably starts the film with one and ends with the other.  I like that better than a sudden across-the-board change of uniform.  Here, you get the sense that Starfleet gives officers some leeway during a uniform transition period.

Comment: @Praxis aww shucks!

Comment: @Praxis I think it's *nice* that they do that, but how scruffy for an institution like Starfleet! They'd have to sort it out before the [Borg] Queen comes for a visit.

Comment: @ThruGog -- apparently the real US military does the same piecemeal change of uniforms, see the answers from Jimmie Ray Giboney and anoxm to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32334/why-didnt-star-trek-the-next-generation-change-their-uniforms-when-stdeep-spa).